# Selenium doesn't find element by id (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

Here is the html element:

```
<button role="button" title="Meeting beitreten" id="interstitial_join_btn" class="style-rest-1IrDU style-theme-green-22KBC style-join-button-yqbh_ style-size-huge-3dFcq style-botton-outline-none-1M0ur" tabindex="1" aria-label="Meeting beitreten" aria-describedby="current_select_status" data-doi="MEETING:JOIN_MEETING:MEETSIMPLE_INTERSTITIAL">Meeting beitreten</button>
```

my code is:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--mute-audio")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/leand/Desktop/kahoot-answer-bot-master/chromedriver.exe",options=option)
browser.get(url + "?launchApp=true")
browser.find_element_by_id('interstitial_join_btn').click()
```

but I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...here is some info about the files etc...
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="interstitial_join_btn"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

What have I done wrong or is there any other way to click on this element?

Comment: Add your selenium code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems synchronization issue.To click Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"pbui_iframe")))    WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"interstitial_join_btn"))).click()
```

Import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

If above code gives you `timeout error` then check if that button present inside an `iframe` or inside `#shadowroot element`

**Update**: element is in iframe need to switch.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://meet37.webex.com/webappng/sites/meet37/meeting/download/7050764c36568ef62dd56dd671cb73c1?launchApp=true")
wait=WebDriverWait(browser,20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"pbui_iframe"))) 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Your full name']"))).send_keys("user1")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Email address']"))).send_keys("Testuser@gmail.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"guest_next-btn"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"interstitial_join_btn"))).click()
```

Comment: I now get the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: @DerNoob : did you import all libraries i have mentioned?

Comment: yes, how can I see if the button is inside an iframe or #shadowroot element?

Comment: @DerNoob : Check your DOM tree above button element if you have parent tag like `iframe` or `shadowroot` ? If you can't then share your url?

Comment: I have an iframe and I switched to it using this code-line: `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('pbui_iframe'))`. But still the same timeout error ...

Comment: @DerNoob : Share your url if possible?

Comment: @DerNoob : Please find the update and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

To select an item on selenium must first be loaded from the browser, so you need to wait some seconds until all html elements is loaded ant then select them

You can do it with the `time.sleep()` function like this:

```py
time.sleep(2.0) // 2.0 = 2seconds
<button role="button" title="Meeting beitreten" id="interstitial_join_btn" class="style-rest-1IrDU style-theme-green-22KBC style-join-button-yqbh_ style-size-huge-3dFcq style-botton-outline-none-1M0ur" tabindex="1" aria-label="Meeting beitreten" aria-describedby="current_select_status" data-doi="MEETING:JOIN_MEETING:MEETSIMPLE_INTERSTITIAL">Meeting beitreten</button>
```